# cant change array elements globally

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

currently im working on a ethereum dapp. i have a solidity file as below

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract ArrayOfBytes32 {
    address creator;
    bytes32[10] bytesArray; // size must be fixed


    function getArray() constant returns (bytes32[10])
    {uint8 x = 0;
        while(x < bytesArray.length)
        {
            bytesArray[x] = "myString"; 
            x++;
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }

    function getValue(uint8 x) constant returns (bytes32)
    {
        return bytesArray[x];
    }
}
```

in this function getArray() returns correctly. But function getValue() always returning default value ie 0000000.
changes made in getArray() are not reflected !! any solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `constant` modifier from `getArray()`. `constant` functions do not write state to the blockchain.